# OpenGL ES 3.2 doesn't recognize gl_in in geometry shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I have the following shader code:

```c
#version 320 es

layout(points) in;
layout(points, max_vertices=1) out;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main() {
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position * transform;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

But when creating the shader program I get the following error:

> ```
> 'gl_in' : undeclared identifier
> 'gl_in' : left of '[' is not of type array, matrix, or vector
> 'gl_Position' : field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side
> 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'const highp float' to 'Position 4-component vector of highp float
> ```

But in https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.html it explicitly states the existance of gl_in (as a built-in variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to Intel UHD graphics not supporting OpenGLES explictly. When I checked what GLSL version was requested it was requesting OpenGL 2.0 which does not support `gl_in` as a built in.